# Get posts by category with pure SQL query

Tags: query, query-posts, sql

I have a `meeting` post type, whose titles automatically get set to a date of the form `m/d/Y`. I have the below query which gets all unique years from the post titles by selecting distinct values after the last `/` inside the post title.

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(post_title, - instr(reverse(post_title), '/') + 1)
AS year FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'meeting'
```

This outputs an array looking something like `["2019", "2018", "2017"]`.

What I want is to refine this down further to be able to consider posts of only a certain category.

Now I know the below example is wrong, since categories are not actually stored on the posts themselves, but basically I want to refine by post category like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(post_title, - instr(reverse(post_title), '/') + 1)
AS year FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'meeting'
AND post_category = 'some_cat_slug'
```

This query is about the extent of my SQL knowledge so I'm not sure how to do the join in order to filter by category.

Edit: To clarify, this is just for generating pagination buttons by year. So in short, I am trying to find all years that have at least one meeting post for a specific category. If this can be done with `WP_Query` only, I'd be happy to hear it.

Edit 2: I've solved my issue by storing the post categories in the title as well. I'll leave this here if anyone else wants to answer though.

Comment: Could you not use the publish date for the meeting? That way you can use `WP_Query` and avoid SQL entirely

Comment: May I ask, do you definitely want raw SQL? (i.e. for queries outside of WP). Otherwise all of this can (and should) be done using `WP_Query` and hooks.

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, it must by done with SQL. The date I am referring to is populated from a custom field and is not the same as the publish date. I do not want to get all the fields either, I just want the unique years. If you want context, this is just for generating pagination buttons by years rather than pages, so really I'm just trying to find all years that have at least one meeting. If you know how to do that with WP_Query I'm all ears.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic check edit

Comment: WP_Query can search by meta values, so if your custom field holds the date and it's not just stored as part of the title then you should be able to avoid a raw SQL query.

Comment: @mrben522 Yes, that date is also on a meta field. However, I am not trying to get the posts themselves. I just want an array of years that have at least one `meeting` post, filtered by category.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you won't use the publish date? If it's for having posts published in the future show, that can be changed, raw SQL is definitely not necessary ( context is important )

Comment: Another solution would to use a custom taxonomy for year, that would simplify your solution a lot.  this could be retroactively applied to existing posts via a relatively simple script.

Comment: @TomJNowell Well, the custom field `date` is the date the meeting occurred, but that may not necessarily be the date it was posted. Especially since this is a new site, and I will be going in and posting all the meetings from previous years as well. If you haven't yet, check my OP edit as I clarify a bit more there. I'm all up for a new way of doing it. This is more of an aggregation than a straight query to get posts.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to get the category by name, this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(post_title, - instr(reverse(post_title), '/') + 1)
AS year FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'meeting'
AND t.name = 'Category Name'
AND tax.taxonomy = 'category'
```

If you know the term_taxonomy_id of your category (mostly, but not always, the term_id), you can accomplish this with fewer left joins like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(post_title, - instr(reverse(post_title), '/') + 1)
AS year FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_type = 'meeting'
AND rel.term_taxonomy_id = <term_taxonomy_id of your category>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: This helped me immensely. Thank you.